# Can we play more than one video from a single AVAsset instance iOS

Tags: ios, avasset

I referred the docs and it says that you may create multiple AVPlayerLayer instances from a single AVAsset object but it nowhere says if we can play more than one video from a single AVAsset instance.

I don't think its possible but still I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to play multiple video with single AVPlayerLayer but second video is covered first video so if you want to see both video at a time than decrease alpha channel of second video to 50% than you see both video.

Comment: Please read the question carefully.I want to use a single avplayer to play multiple urls.Is it possible?

Comment: do you want to multiple video at same time?

Comment: No not at the same time.I am playing a video,and I have trimmed that video.Now I want to play that trimmed video.

Comment: Than fine you will use same AVPlayer object to play second video.

Comment: but how ?shall i change the url?Is that all?

Comment: if you put static url than it's not possible..But if your url is come from your web service than apply on AVPlayer object directly.